# JSF How to populate a new page without using session scope?

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

I've read many posts trying to find the best approach for what seems a simple problem in JSF but haven't found a good answer.

I'm trying to invoke a method and as a result forward to a new page.  For example, a function gets called to save data which would store a record and then forward a user to a new page which uses that data in some way.

An obvious solution would be to generate the second managed bean manually, populate it and add it to session scope but then the bean remains in session scope.  Is there a way of passing the  relevant data to the second bean?

What would be ideal is to somehow be able to pass a parameter to the second bean so that it's @PostConstruct method could use this to populate.  I don't really want the parameters to appear in the URL though as they may be data values you don't want to share.

Hope this make sense, any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Use view scope or request scope for the beans. To pass parameters you can use flash scope's map. Anyway, you should try something and share it here.

Answer (score 0):

before navigating to the next page, place all the required data in request scope. Then in next bean, check in the constructor for the value which you have set in request scope before navigation and populate the new object.